# Passing an array of object having name and value attribute as query param

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, model, query-string

Here is scenario.

I have below pojo

```
Property {
  String name;
  String value;
}
```

I want to pass an array of above pojo as query param. How do i do that.

Something like

```
http://myservice.com?property:name=n1&property:value=v1&property:name=n2&property:value=v2
```

And I want to figure out at service end that v1 is the value for n1.

Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you can pass this into a URL as the following -

```
  sample.php?arr_args[key1]=value1&arr_args[key2]=value2
```